# How to use Index Marks in "speech-dispatcher"?

Tags: c, text-to-speech

So, question like in theme: "How to use Index Marks in speech-dispatcher?" I hear many about it but can't find any tutorial with how to use it in SPD_MODE_THREADED. The main problem is when you send "SPEAK" command, you can't change data mode to SPD_DATA_SSML. And I think I doing something wrong. So, who knows how to use this Index Marks, tutorials is very acceptable too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**, this is the way to set index marks in speech-dispatcher:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( m_connection->ssip_mutex );

spd_execute_command_wo_mutex( m_connection, "SET SELF SSML_MODE on" );

spd_execute_command_wo_mutex( m_connection, "SPEAK" );

char * reply = spd_send_data_wo_mutex( m_connection, "<speak>Hello, <mark name=\"mark1\"/> how does it work?</speak>", SPD_NO_REPLY );
delete[] reply;

spd_execute_command_wo_mutex( m_connection, "\r\n." );

spd_execute_command_wo_mutex( m_connection, "SET SELF SSML_MODE off" );

pthread_mutex_unlock( m_connection->ssip_mutex );
```

Where `<mark name=\"mark1\"/>` is index mark. And `mark1` is index mark name.

This docs is very useful for low level speech-dispatcher communication: http://cvs.freebsoft.org/doc/speechd/ssip.html#Top