# How to programmatically send a unix socket command to a system server autospawned by browser or convert JavaScript to C++ souce code for Chromium?

Tags: javascript, c++, linux, chromium, espeak

Presently the implementation of the [Web Speech API Specification](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/webspeechapi.html) by [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=795371) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425523) does not support parsing [Speech Synthesis Markup Language](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-speech-synthesis11-20100907/) (SSML) when SSML is set at `text` property of [`SpeechSyntheisUtterance`](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html#utterance-attributes) instance and passed to [`window.speechSynthesis.speak()`](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/webspeechapi.html#dfn-ttsspeak) call; see [SSML parsing implementation at browsers](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-voice/2017OctDec/0000.html); [5.2.3 SpeechSynthesisUtterance Attributes](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2017Dec/0000.html);  [How to set options of commands called by browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991314/how-to-set-options-of-commands-called-by-browser).

Chromium source code for the unix socket connect to [`speech-dispatcher`](https://devel.freebsoft.org/doc/speechd/speech-dispatcher.html) connection appears to be at [/src/chrome/browser/speech/tts_linux.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/speech/tts_linux.cc?ssfr=1&l=119)

```
  {
    // spd_open has memory leaks which are hard to suppress.
    // http://crbug.com/317360
    ANNOTATE_SCOPED_MEMORY_LEAK;
    conn_ = libspeechd_loader_.spd_open(
        "chrome", "extension_api", NULL, SPD_MODE_THREADED);
  }
```

which appears to be reflected at `/run/user/1000/speech-dispatcher/log`

```
speechd: Updating client specific settings "linux:chrome:extension_api"
```

Chromium source code at [/src/third_party/speech-dispatcher/libspeechd.h](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/speech-dispatcher/libspeechd.h?q=SSML&dr=CSs&l=62)

appears to define the `SSML_DATA_MODE` described at `speech-dispatcher` documentation

The [`speech-dispatcher`](https://devel.freebsoft.org/doc/speechd/speech-dispatcher.html) documentation states that the user configuration file can be used to set parameters for specific clients

> **4.1.6 Parameter Settings Commands**
>
> The following parameter setting commands are available. For
>   configuration and history clients there are also functions for setting
>   the value for some other connection and for all connections. They are
>   listed separately below.
>
> C API function: `int spd_set_data_mode(SPDConnection *connection,
>   SPDDataMode mode)` Set Speech Dispatcher data mode. Currently, plain
>   text and SSML are supported. SSML is especially useful if you want to
>   use index marks or include changes of voice parameters in the text.
>
> mode is the requested data mode: `SPD_DATA_TEXT` or `SPD_DATA_SSML`.

`SPD_DATA_SSML` is not set to `on` at the establishment of the [SSIP](https://devel.freebsoft.org/doc/speechd/ssip.html#Top) connection from Chromium to `speech-dispatcher`, for example as demonstrated by @xmash at [How to use Index Marks in "speech-dispatcher"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880234/how-to-use-index-marks-in-speech-dispatcher/14896544#14896544)

```
spd_execute_command_wo_mutex( m_connection, "SET SELF SSML_MODE on" );
```

nor is it possible to pass options to the default speech synthesis module, `m` for [`espeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) or `-x` for [`spd-say`](https://devel.freebsoft.org/doc/speechd/speech-dispatcher.html#spd_002dsay).

With `LogLevel` set to `4` or `5` `/run/user/1000/speech-dispatcher/log` lists the communication between Chromium (client) and `speech-dispatcher`

```
speechd:    Module set parameters
```

(server) which can also be viewed at `stdout` using the `PID` within `/run/user/1000/speech-dispatcher/pid` and `strace`, see [Is there a way to intercept interprocess communication in Unix/Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1907)

```
$ sudo strace -ewrite -p $PID

write(22, "216 OK OUTPUT MODULE SET\r\n", 26) = 26
```

There does not appear to be an option to set SSML parsing to on from either `speechd.conf` or `espeak.conf` following running

```
$ spd-conf -u
```

While attempting to parse SSML using JavaScript at [SpeechSynthesisSSMLParser](https://github.com/guest271314/SpeechSynthesisSSMLParser) encountered a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=797624) at Chromium when trying to parse `<break>` element, where it is not clear whether `spd-say` is called or the default output module, e.g., `espeak` is run when `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` is called by the browser; see [/src/out/Debug/gen/library_loaders/libspeechd.h](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/out/Debug/gen/library_loaders/libspeechd.h).

Created an approach to use `php` to call `espeak` using `shell_exec()` which returns the expected result

```
// JavaScript
async function SSMLStream({ssml="", options=""}) {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("ssml", ssml);
  fd.append("options", options);

  const request = await fetch("speak.php", {method:"POST", body:fd});
  const response = await request.arrayBuffer();
  return response;
}

let ssml = `<speak version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US"> 
             Here are <say-as interpret-as="characters">SSML</say-as> samples. 
             Hello universe, how are you today? 
             Try a date: <say-as interpret-as="date" format="dmy" detail="1">10-9-1960</say-as> 
             This is a <break time="2500ms" /> 2.5 second pause. 
             This is a <break /> sentence break</prosody> <break />
             <voice name="us-en+f3" rate="x-slow" pitch="0.25">espeak using</voice> 
             PHP and <voice name="en-us+f2"> <sub alias="JavaScript">JS</sub></voice>
           </speak>`;

SSMLStream({ssml, options:"-v en-us+f1"})
.then(async(data) => {

    let context = new AudioContext();
    let source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = await context.decodeAudioData(data);
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start()

})
// PHP
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST["ssml"])) {
    header("Content-Type: audio/x-wav");
    $options = $_POST["options"];
    echo shell_exec("espeak -m --stdout " . $options . " '" . $_POST["ssml"] . "'");
  };
```

Requirement:

Parse the SSML set at text property of `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` using the existing capabilities of the native program called to convert text to speech by `speech-dispatcher` output module using default browser capabilities.

Questions:

1) How to programmatically listen for the the `PID` when `speech-dispatcher --spawn-communication-method unix_socket --socket-path /run/user/1000/speech-dispatcher/speechd.sock` is called by Chromium browser, then call `spd_execute_command_wo_mutex` or `spd_execute_command_wo_mutex` to the `speech-dispatcher` server using the established unix socket connection as client (Chromium) with `"SET SELF SSML_MODE on"` as second parameter to turn on SSML parsing for all calls to `window.speechSynthesis.speak()` at Chromium browser?

2) If 1) is not possible, what needs to be adjusted at Chromium source code to turn on SSML parsing for the unix socket connection, e.g., at [tools/generate_library_loader/generate_library_loader.py](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/tools/generate_library_loader/generate_library_loader.py?q=tools/generate_library_loader/generate_library_loader.py&ct=rc&cd=1&dr)?

3) If 1) and 2) are not viable options, how to convert the JavaScript and PHP code into C++ code in the format used by Chromium browser; and how to build Chromium with the patch included; for the purpose of exposing a `speak` function with accepts parameters which can be passed to a native speech synthesis application where SSML is parsed and the resulting audio output is returned to JavaScript caller as an `ArrayBuffer`?

4) If options other than 1), 2) and 3) are available and capable of meeting requirement how can we resolve the inquiry programmatically; without having to start a local server manually at `terminal`?