# Is it possible to use a c++ library in a javascript application

Tags: javascript, c++, libraries

I'm trying to build a javascript app and i need to use a c++ library. Is there any way to include a c++ library in a javascript application?

Comment: Maybe write bindings for it? However that requires some work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can utilize [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) to convert C++ to JavaScript. You can alternatively

- use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging) to communicate with a shell script
- use a local server to `POST` commands to a shell script which runs the native shell script, e.g., see `shell_exec()` calls at PHP at [How to programmatically send a unix socket command to a system server autospawned by browser or convert JavaScript to C++ souce code for Chromium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219981/how-to-programmatically-send-a-unix-socket-command-to-a-system-server-autospawne)

Comment: In addition to these options, Node.js supports [native addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Node.js and you library is provided as DLL, you could use [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) (Foreign Function Intergface). For other options check this [post](https://nodeaddons.com/getting-your-c-to-the-web-with-node-js/).